# Learn Ruby the Hardway ex. 42. 2 classes in 2 files

Tags: ruby, class, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I understand how classes work and how to make them, but the 2nd extra credit of the exercice says to create a two-class version, in 2 different files.

I tried different things, but I can't figure out how to make it work...

I don't know if I'm not searching at the right places, but I can't find any help on that, nor find any solution...

If anyone could help me on that, it would be much appreciated :)

here is the exercice : http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex42.html

What I have tried so far :

```
map.rb
class Map

with all the methods in here (death(), central_corridor(), etc.)
```

then

```
engine.rb
class Engine
require './map.rb'

  def initialize(start)
    @quips = [
      "You died. You kinda suck at this.",
      "Nice job, you died... jackass.",
      "Suck a luser."
    ]

    @start = start
    puts "in init @start = " + @start.inspect
  end

  def prompt()
    print "> "
  end

  def play()
    puts "@start => " + @start.inspect
    @next_room = @start

    while true
      puts "\n--------"
      room = method(@next_room)
      @next_room = room.call()
    end
  end

end

a_game = Engine.new(:central_corridor)
a_game.play()
```

So basically what I did is get the methods used for "actions" in the game (the rooms, death, etc.. and put them in a class Map in map.rb, and then called in engine.rb where i have my class Engine with the "general" methods/variables like prompt, play, start.

The error I get is

```
engine.rb:24:in `method': undefined method `central_corridor' for class `Engine'
```

I understand it means ruby tries to find a method "central_corridor" in the class engine, but it's in the class map in map.rb and I can't figure out what to do, either it's some variable modifications or just some things to add... :(

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include what you've tried and the error messages you get from your attempts?

Comment: Don't `require` the map class *inside* the engine class, put that before the class declaration. But an `Engine` instance method (defined via `def` inside the `Engine` declaration) requires an instance of an `Engine` to execute.

Comment: What do you mean by it requires an instance of an Engine to execute? The whole point of the exercise of having the 2 classes in 2 files is to use an instance of map while being in engine, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an instance of class `Map`, which is what you need to be able to call `central_corridor`. Add this into `initialize`:

```
@map=Map.new
```

And change `room = method(@next_room)` to `room=@map.method(@next_room)`.

---

Although this isen't your question, I have a feeling that if `Map` never changes (you have methods for everything in the map), that you make all of the methods class methods and just use the class `Map` for your map. But by good design principles, you should probably make the map have a `Hash` of lambdas representing the areas. That way, you can have more than one map

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is solved !

But now i have another problem, which is the opposite :)

/Users/Jonathan/Hardway/map.rb:20:in `central_corridor': undefined method `prompt' for #<Map:0x007fb928846e88> (NoMethodError)

thanks a lot

Comment: @Jauny: Glad to help. When you find an answer that solves your problem, you can click on the check under the vote count to accept the answer.

Comment: @Jauny: What are the return values of the `Map.central_corridor` method? Does it every return `:prompt`?

Comment: Don't worry, I put prompt into map.rb since it's where it is used, and it fixed it :)